# How many distinct values can be obtained for the expression $1/2/3/5/7/11/13/17$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

What is a simple way to solve this problem? I can solve the problem by counting all possibilities.

> How many distinct values can be obtained for the expression $1/2/3/5/7/11/13/17$ if an unlimited number of parentheses may be placed in the expression?

Comment: all the divisors are prime numbers is important here - I don't know how to solve it - but I would start by considering 1/2/3 then 1/2/3/5 to see how it works - then extend